# PHP FastCgi running as IUSR instead of IIS APPPOOL/xxx

Tags: php, iis, permissions

An IIS website is run via an Application Pool which has its Identity advanced property set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. The website runs PHP scripts via a FastCGI handler. These scripts try to write to a file but the access is denied even the application pool user has enough permission. I have run ProcMon and it shows that the scripts are trying to open the files using IUSR instead of the application pool user.

- Website example.com

  - Basic Settings - Application Pool = example.com
  - Basic Settings - Connect As = Application user (pass-through authentication)
- Application Pool example.com

  - Advanced Settings - Process Model - Identity - ApplicationPoolIdentity
- Script tries to write to a file

  - C:\ABC\test.txt
- The directory C:\ABC has permission

  - IIS APPPOOL\example.com - Full control, Type Allow, Applies to This folder, subfolders and files

When I open the scripts url, I get
`PHP Warning:  fopen(C:\ABC\test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

When I run Sysinternal's ProcMon I see:

- Event

  - Operation CreateFile
  - Result Access Denied
  - Path C:\ABC
  - Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Syncchronize
  - ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete
  - Impersonating: **NT AUTHORITY\IUSR**
- Process

  - Path …\php-cgi.exe
  - User: IIS APPPOOL\example.com

How to fix it so the file is accessed using the example.com user?

Comment: Good question I normally just go screw it and set the upload directories  "everyone" can read and write  :D so would be interested if this gets answered :D

Comment: It runs as expected on another server but something is wrong on this one and I could not find what it is.

Answer (score 6):

Finally found it. There is one more place that it needs to be set it up.

`Site -> Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication -> Edit to "Application Pool Identity"`

Source: [PHP on IIS 7.5/W2K8 using IUSR Account not IIS_APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool](https://serverfault.com/questions/410585/php-on-iis-7-5-w2k8-using-iusr-account-not-iis-apppool-defaultapppool)